# How to correctly take GoogleMaps coordinates and post them to a Webhook using python 3 and json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, geocoding

## GEOCODING AND POSTING JSON FILES TO A WEBHOOK

To begin with, my assignment is automated program that allows the user to enter in an address and returns the lat and long with googlemaps API (basically geocoding), then the program posts the coordinates to a webhook in json format on a website called Datazar.

### WHAT THE CONCEPT IS ABOUT

The idea is that rather than having to use the curl to send json files with terminal, I'm trying to send the json file through python without ever having to exit the program making it completely automated. I've been successful with retrieving latitude and longitude coordinates with the googlemaps api and running it through terminal in python 3.

The problem begins right when I use the json and request module to post coordinates to a webhook. I'm not sure my code is formatted correctly.

#### This is the attempt that i've tried with posting with json:

```
I assigned the lat and long to a variable.

coordinates = geocode_result['geometry']['location']

url = 'https://webhooks.datazar.com/w69017d25-f1b9-4372-8e6f- 
15a4637ad94a'

requests.post(url, json=coordinates)
```

This is the entire code. (I've taken away the api key for 
obvious reasons.)

```
import googlemaps

import requests

import json

api_key = "<googleapikey>"
gm = googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)

address = input("Please enter the address: ")

geocode_result = gm.geocode(address)[0]

print("The Latitude and Longitude are now posted to your 
webhook." )
coordinates = geocode_result['geometry']['location']

url = 'https://webhooks.datazar.com/w69017d25-f1b9-4372-8e6f- 
15a4637ad94a'

requests.post(url, json=coordinates)
```

Every time I run the program through terminal I receive the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datazargeocode.py", line 21, in

```
requests.post(url, json=coordinates)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return

```
request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return

```
session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request

```
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send

```
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
```

Comment: Since this issue is caused by a `ConnectionError` I tried connecting to the url you provided for Datazar and got no response from their server. It seems that this issue is happening just because the `webhooks.datazar.com` site is down, or perhaps you have the wrong url.

Comment: I see. thanks so much for your help!